# jQuery - disable button click until css animation ends

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I'm trying to disable button until the CSS animation ends.

The code responsible for triggering click event:

```
$($controls__right).on('click', function () {
    replace_images();
    direction = 1;
    reload_content(direction);
});
```

The function which animates the image. Until this part of code isn't executed the button should be **disabled**, after execution **enabled**.

```
function replace_images() {
    $current__images = $('.device__screen');
    $current__texts = $('.text-area');
    $($current__images[0].children[0]).css({
        '-webkit-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        '-moz-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        '-ms-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        '-o-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        'animation': 'scroll_down 1s'
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $($current__images[0].children[0]).remove();
    }, 1000);

    $($current__texts[0].children[0]).remove();
}
```

Comment: write a toggle function to disable/enable the button, and then call this function at start and end of the replace_images() function

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of `animationend` event at this context,

```
$element.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend', function () {
    // enable or disable whatever buttons you want
});
```

where `$element` is going to be animated by css animations.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using [callbacks](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp):

```
function replace_images() {
    $("#button").prop('disabled', true); //disable

    $current__images = $('.device__screen');
    $current__texts = $('.text-area');
    $($current__images[0].children[0]).css({
        '-webkit-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        '-moz-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        '-ms-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        '-o-animation': 'scroll_down 1s',
        'animation': 'scroll_down 1s'
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $($current__images[0].children[0]).remove(function() {
            $("#button").prop('disabled', false) //enable
        });
    );
    }, 1000);

    $($current__texts[0].children[0]).remove();
}
```